# Checking a list of strings as palindrome in python 3

Tags: python, palindrome

I am checking a list of strings if every string in the list is palindrome or not.
I need a for loop to test the function for all strings in the list.

l=["Anna",
"Civic",
"Computer"
]

First, i write a code just like this below:

```
def is_it_palindrome(list):
for x in list:
    if x.upper() == x[::-1].upper():
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

when I run this code, it only returns one True. not True True False
Then I change my code:

```
def is_it_palindrome(list):
for x in list:
    if x.upper() == x[::-1].upper():
        print("True")
    else:
        print("False")
```

It works. However, Could anyone tell me why the first one do not work and the second one is true or not. 
Thank you.

Comment: printing vs returning a result and not printing it... try `print(is_it_palindrome(list)` (fix your indent! don't use `list`)

Comment: `return` finishes the  function execution. If you want to collect multiple results, either put them into a list and return the list, or use `yield`.

Comment: what do you want to do? check if all strings are a palindrome? or return a list of booleans?

Comment: Just return a list of booleans. Thank you.@Jean-FrançoisFabre

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason that your  first def isn't work is since you are using `return` with causing your function to return value and stop the loop.
I suggest you to use `map` built-in function as following, just notice that it can be written in a better way

```
str_list =["Anna", "Civic", "Computer" ]

def is_it_palindrome(word):
    return word.upper() == word[::-1].upper()

list(map(is_it_palindrome, str_list))
```

EDIT -
this can also be written with lmbda function, which is more Pythonic way, but I got confuse with it some times.

```
str_list =["Anna", "Civic", "Computer" ]
list(map(lambda x: x.upper() == x[::-1].upper() , str_list ))
```

Comment: However,  when I run the first code, it shows 'list' object is not callable.

Comment: @Huizhong, it's run perfect on my computer, the only thing that I can can think of, is that you called some variable in the name `list` with is shadowing the built-in function `list`